# define and execute a composed ant task in java

Tags: java, ant

It's possible define and execute a composed ant task into java application?
What i need to do is like this:

```
<copy todir="dirDest">
  <fileset dir="sourceDir">
    <exclude name="exFile.ext" />
    <exclude name="dirEx" />
  </fileset>
</copy>
```

The example explain what i need to do in my java application, or rather, copy a directory content into another with some exception.
The execution of the single task is very [simple](http://ant.apache.org/manual/antexternal.html) but i can't find a tutorial for do my example.

Comment: Ant is the wrong tool for this.  Write the code yourself.  Start by reading the documentation of the [Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html), [Paths](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) and [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) classes.  See also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html .

Comment: you are right @VGR , my java application is a "wrapper" for a complex copy (and more) operations and i like reuse the good ant classes :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reply to my question...

After reading the apache ant class [code documents](http://ant.apache.org/srcdownload.cgi), i have found how build the task:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.Project;
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Copy;
import org.apache.tools.ant.types.FileSet;

//Create the new copy class
Copy copier = new Copy();
//Set the target directory wrapped into File object
copier.setTodir(new File("my/target/directory"));
//The project's definition is requested for the execution of Copy
copier.setProject(new Project());

//Before run its request to define the FileSet object
FileSet fs = new FileSet();

//Now setup the base directory to copy
fs.setDir(new File("my/source/directory"));
//If its require, define the inner file or directory to exclude from the copy action
fs.setExcludes("fileExcluded");
fs.setExcludes("directory/to/exclude");

//Link the FileSet to copy
copier.addFileset(fs);
//And go!
copier.execute();
```